# I have to switch the alert and accept it and back to default window..I need groovy code tor that in selenium webdriver sampler in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have to switch the alert and accept it.

And i have go back to that window.

Could you please provide groovy code with respect to selenium webdriver sampler..

Answer (score 0):

Groovy is almost 100% Java-compatible hence you can find the example code for working with alerts in [Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/alerts/), with regards to specifics of the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) you will need to change `driver` to `WDS.browser`

Example code with necessary imports:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert
import org.openqa.selenium.By
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait

import java.time.Duration


WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, Duration.ofSeconds(10))
WDS.browser.get("https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/alerts/")
WDS.browser.findElement(By.linkText("See a sample confirm")).click()
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent())
Alert alert = WDS.browser.switchTo().alert()
String text = alert.getText()
WDS.log.info("Alert text: " + text)
alert.dismiss()
WDS.log.info("Current page title: " + WDS.browser.getTitle())
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

And demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)